# Unrestricted comprehension with non-circular formulas?

Tags: set-theory

Define a *non-circular formula* to be a formula $\varphi$ in which we can assign a *level* $|x| \in \mathbb{N}$ to each variable $x$ in $\varphi$ (whether it's free or bound) such that whenever $\varphi$ contains $x \in y$, $|x| < |y|$.

Then, for any non-circular formula $\varphi(x)$ with one free variable $x$, we add a non-circular comprehension axiom saying that $\{x : \varphi(x)\}$ exists.

Is ZFC - comprehension + non-circular unrestricted comprehension consistent?

Comment: Is equality allowed, or is that interpreted using the Axiom of Extensionality? Otherwise, $\{ x \mid x = x \}$ would be valid.

Comment: @Hayden So is $\{\,x\mid \exists y\colon x\in y\,\}$ (with $|x|=1$, $|y|=2$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Definitely, and that unambiguously fulfills the criteria.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather close to Quine's theory [New Foundations (NF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations) and its relatives.

NF consists of **stratified comprehension** (the standard term for what you call "non-circular unrestricted comprehension") and extensionality. Many basic principles (e.g. Union and Pairing) are derivable from these. In particuar, if we drop Choice, Separation, Replacement, and Foundation from ZF and add stratified comprehension we get NF.

There is however a surprisingly deep issue here: [**NF disproves the axiom of choice**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117009/understanding-speckers-disproof-of-the-axiom-of-choice-in-new-foundations). So it's crucial that we get rid of choice as well.

To make matters worse, **it's currently unknown whether NF is consistent** (even under [rather strong set-theoretic assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal)); a claimed consistency proof has been [given by Randall Holmes](https://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/nfproof/leeds.pdf) and several variations (at least in presentation), but as far as I know it hasn't been universally accepted yet. Meanwhile NFU, gotten by dropping Extensionality from NF, is known to be consistent, as are many of its variants (including NFU+AC).

Comment: For what it's worth, I think Randall's proof is quite interesting, and has one of the most elaborate permutation models in the history of set theory (and quite possibly rivaling and surpassing even my own work in terms of complexity of constructions in choiceless set theory).

Answer (score 2):

From the **Pairing** axiom of ZF, we know that for every set $x$ there exists a set $y:=\{x\}(:=\{x,x\})$ such that $x\in y$. Therefore, 
$$ a:=\{\,x_{\color{red}1}\mid \exists y_{\color{red}2}\colon x_{\color{red}1}\in y_{\color{red}2}\,\}$$
is a set in your theory and is the set of all sets. Consequently $a\in a$, whch contradicts the Axiom of **Foundation** in ZF. More precisely, Foundation states that $b:=\{a\}$ contains an element disjoint from $b$ - but the only possible such element is $a$ and that has $a$ as common element with $b$.

So your theory is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks! What about without foundation? Would there still be a contradiction then?

Comment: @user741340 Because you still have restricted comprehension, the existence of a set of all sets means that Russel's paradox can be performed.

Comment: I don't, the new axiom replaces the restricted comprehension.

Comment: @user741340 You'd also have to get rid of Replacement, though - and surprisingly, *Choice* is also a problem. See my answer.